# Toggle between functions when key is pressed using Python

Tags: python, function, toggle, turtle-graphics

Hey Guys I am doing an assingment for uni and I have to make a colouring book which enables the user to swap between two modes using the space key. In the first mode the user must be able to move the turtle with out drawing any lines and the second mode must initiate the paint brush mode where the user can draw.I want to be able to toggle between penup() and the pendown() turtle functions when the space button is pressed. Any ideas?

This is what I have so far:

```
from turtle import *
bgpic("Colour_A_Turkey.gif") # change this to change the picture

# PUT YOUR CODE HERE
setup(800,600)
home()
pen_size = 2
color("red")
title("Colouring Book")
speed("fastest") # Doesn't make any difference to accuracy, just makes turtle turn animation faster.
drawdist=10 # Distance in pixels pen travels when arrow key is pressed

penup()
###################BUTTON INSTRUCTIONS########################
def move_up():
        seth(90)
        forward(drawdist)

def move_down():
        seth(270)
        forward(drawdist)

def move_left():
        seth(180)
        forward(drawdist)

def move_right():
        seth(0)
        forward(drawdist)

def space_bar():

        if isdown()==True:
                penup()

        if isdown()==False:
                       pendown()
####Change pen color####
def red():
        color("red")

def green():
        color("green")

def blue():
        color("blue")


################BUTTON TRIGGERS##################
s= getscreen()

s.onkey(move_up,"Up")

s.onkey(move_down,"Down")

s.onkey(move_left,"Left")

s.onkey(move_right,"Right")

s.onkey(space_bar,"space")

s.onkey(red,"r")

s.onkey(green,"g")

s.onkey(blue,"b")

listen()

done()
```

Comment: just edited the original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When space_bar is called, isdown() is always true.
Do you want to toggle or draw only when the spacebar is pressed?

If you want to toggle, here's what you can do:

```
current_state = penup
next_state = pendown
def space_bar():
    global current_state, next_state
    next_state()
    current_state, next_state = next_state, current_state
```

Comment: I want to toggle between just moving the turtle and the painting mode please

Comment: thanks bro it works now wish i could vote you up but i don't have enough rep :(

Comment: Happy to help. I'm also new here, but I think you can mark it as the answer to your question or something...

Comment: Ahh The massive tick, how could I miss that?? Biggest Noob Right Here

Comment: Right, I didn't know about itertools. Cool.

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import cycle

funcs = cycle([f1, f2])
next(funcs)() # alternates
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you toggle between pen up and pen down.

```
up = False

def pen_up():

    global up
    up = not up
    if up:
        t.penup()
    else:
        t.pendown()

ts.onkey(pen_up, 'space')
```